# Return single view on every controller action in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to return same view for every controller action request in asp.net mvc3 .What is the best possible way to achieve this. I dont want to write view name in every controller action

Comment: I'm interested to know the real-life application of this approach.

Comment: Are you even interested in answers or you just throw your questions here with no intention?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
Return RedirecToAction(ActionName)
```

so you may have something like

```
<ActionName("PageX")> _
Function PageX() As ActionResult
  Return RedirectToAction("CommonView")
End Function

<ActionName("PageY")> _
Function PageY() As ActionResult
  Return RedirectToAction("CommonView")
End Function

<ActionName("PageZ")> _
Function PageZ() As ActionResult
  Return RedirectToAction("CommonView")
End Function

<ActionName("CommonView")> _
Function CommonView() As ActionResult
  Return View()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it fora single Controller, then override `OnActionExecuted` in this controller:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;

    if (viewResult != null)
    {
        viewResult.ViewName = "view-name";
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

If you want it for whole app, override `ViewEngine`:

```
public class RazorViewEngineViewMobileSupport : RazorViewEngine
{
    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
    {
        return base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, "view-name", useCache);
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        return base.FindView(controllerContext, "view-name", masterName, useCache);
    }
}
```